# Gatsby build / SSR swapping out components causing display errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, styled-components, framer-motion

Update: the below has been resolved, but I'm running into a similar issue:

In my gallery template (for an example page [see here](https://jenniferkshields.nz/shot-on-iphone-january-2020) everything loads fine if navigated to via the site. On refresh, the grid parent div (GalleryGrid in styled-components) is erased/unstyled/replaced with a blank div. This actually happens after refresh, during Gatsby's hydration.

I've tried replacing the styled component with a regular div styled manually, with no luck. Unsure what's going on!

---

I'm running into a really strange error!

I've built a site using Gatsby, sourcing from Prismic.io, and using styled-components to style. I use framer-motion for page transitions and have added my layout component to gatsby-browser so that only page content gets transitioned, and have added similar code to gatsby-ssr to fix some initial ssr errors.

What's happening now is that whenever a page other than an index is visited directly (try [this one](https://jenniferkshields.nz/catalogue)) some components are not rendered properly. On this example, the date towards the top of the page is replaced with a `<Body>` component (which is styled differently to the intended `<Date>` component), and the actual content has been truncated and only shows the first `<p>`.

If you navigate to the 'portfolio' section and then navigate back to the Catalogue page, the page shows correctly - the date is now a `<Date>` component and the whole body text is displayed.

A similar error happens with 'essay' nodes - for example, on [this page](https://jenniferkshields.nz/sometimes-my-layers-clash-with-your-layers) the image is intended to be in a component called `ImageContainer` but is replaced by an extra `EssayContainer` when refreshed or accessed directly (instead of navigating to the page via site navigation).

I honestly have no clue what's going on here or what could be causing this error - whether I've done something wrong or this is a bug in Gatsby's SSR or styled-components/the gatsby SC plugin. It works as expected when running `gatsby develop`, so must be something in the build or the SSR.

My gatsby-browser:

```
const transitionDelay = 500

export const wrapPageElement = ({ element, props }) => {
  return <Layout {...props}>{element}</Layout>
}

export const shouldUpdateScroll = ({
  routerProps: { location },
  getSavedScrollPosition,
}) => {
  if (location.action === "PUSH") {
    window.setTimeout(() => window.scrollTo(0, 0), transitionDelay)
  } else {
    const savedPosition = getSavedScrollPosition(location)
    window.setTimeout(
      () => window.scrollTo(...(savedPosition || [0, 0])),
      transitionDelay
    )
  }
  return false
}
```

And my gatsby-ssr:

```
const transitionDelay = 500

export const wrapPageElement = ({ element, props }) => {
  return <Layout {...props}>{element}</Layout>
}
```

And my repo is [here](https://github.com/jenkshields/jenniferkshields.nz).

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be two issues!

The problem with some components being swapped on build was due to a media query library I was using - `react-responsive`- not having SSR support. I migrated to `@artsy/fresnel` and that resolved a bunch of the issues.

The problem with the content being truncated seems to be an issue with styled-components not playing so nicely with SSR. I had styled components setting inner HTML directly - nesting another div inside the component and setting the html from there did the trick:

```
<Description>
          <div
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
              __html: data.prismicGallery.data.description.html,
            }}
          />
        </Description>
```

This resolves almost everything - I'm still having a problem with Gatsby's hydration replacing/unstyling some elements, but I suspect that's a different issue (added to original question).